# Find the points at which an IVP admits at least two solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the IVP:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x + |\sin(y)|$$

$$y(x_0) = y_0$$

Find the points in $\mathbb R^2$ at which this IVP admits at least two solutions.

Clearly, $f(x,y) = x + |\sin(y)|$ is Lipschitz with respect to $y$ everywhere. Doesn't the existence-uniqueness theorem guarantee that a unique solution exists at any point in $\mathbb R^2$? Is this a trick question?

Thanks.

Comment: your reasoning that there are initial values for which the ivl has multiple solutions looks good to me.

Comment: Indeed, this IVP has a unique solution for any initial data.